# O que significa NaN no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nan

Quando temos um erro na soma de um número com JavaScript, é retornado `NaN`.

Exemplo:

```
parseInt('a') + 3; //NaN
```

O que significa `NaN`?

Comment: Creio que seja `Not a Number`, mas não tenho certeza, por isso irei esperar uma resposta também.

Comment: NÃO ACREDITO! Ninguém linkou pro "Wat", explicação definitiva do NaN: [Wat by Gary Bernhardt \[with Captions\]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20BySC_6HyY)

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk "WAT" array.join("wat" -1) + "batman"; fellings hhusahuss

Comment: Discussão no meta: [É errado perguntar por coisas que se acham facilmente (como alguns julgam) no Google?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/%C3%89-errado-perguntar-por-coisas-que-se-acham-facilmente-como-alguns-julgam-no-go)

Comment: Por mais inacreditável que pareça, _"**N**ot **a** **N**number"_ é um número

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> A propriedade global `NaN` é um valor especial que significa *Not-A-Number* (não é um número).

#### Fonte: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Diz a descrição lá:

`NaN` é uma propriedade do objeto global, não re-escrevível, não configurável e não enumerável.

Nos navegadores modernos, o `NaN` é uma propriedade somente de leitura e não configurável. Mesmo quando não for este o caso, evite sobrescrevê-lo.

Não é usual a utilização do `NaN`. Ele é retornado quando uma operação matemática falha (por exemplo: `Math.sqrt(-1)`), ou quando uma função tenta transformar uma string em inteiro por exemplo `parseInt("blabla")`.

`NaN` valida `false` quando convertido em *Booleano* e pode usar-se [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) para verificar se um valor é `NaN`.

Answer (score 17):

**Definição e Uso**
A propriedade NaN representa um valor `"Not-a-Number".` 
Esta propriedade indica que um valor não é um número legal.

A propriedade NaN é a mesma que a propriedade Number.NaN

Também é retornado NaN quando uma operação matemática não retorna um valor compreensível ou quando você tenta somar alguns números, mas em algum dos seus campos não existe um valor, e não há um Try Cath para tratar a exceção, sendo assim, ele não consegue concluir a operação matemática.

Answer (score 16):

NaN significa Not-A-Number.

Significa que algo não é um número válido.

No caso, você está tentando fazer um parser de 'a' para INT, mas 'a' não é um número, assim é gerado o erro NaN (Not-a-number).

mais informações: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_nan.asp

Answer (score 14):

A propriedade `NaN` representa "**N**ot -**a**- **N**umber".

Esta propriedade indica que um valor não é um número legal.

[fonte - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_nan.asp)

Answer (score 3):

A propriedade global NaN é um valor especial que significa Not-A-Number (não é um número).

No exemplo em questão, é uma das situações que é retornado o valor 'NaN', no caso a conversão de uma string 'alfabeto' para numero.

Você pode utilizar a função isNaN() para verificar se um, calculo, conversão, valor é igual a 'NaN'.
Vide : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Isso já foi respondido anteriormente, inclusive o link é o mesmo da resposta do @Sergio, porém está traduzido.