# Por que a constante NAN é avaliada como Verdadeiro ao testá-la com is_numeric?

Tags: php, números, nan

Eu estava fazendo um teste com a constante `NAN` em PHP, pois até então eu nunca tinha usado a mesma. Fiz testes por curiosidade.

Percebi uma coisa interessante. Ao chamar a função `is_numeric` em `NAN` o resultado foi `TRUE`.

Veja

```
 is_numeric(NAN); // bool(true)
```

A prova no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/uBGzBa)

O que achei contráditório é que eu aprendi aqui no site que  [NaN significa "Not a number"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92169/o-que-significa-nan-no-javascript). E justamente a função chamada `is_numeric` retorna `True` ???

Bem, será que existe alguma teoria para explicar isso? Ou isso seria algum bug da função.

Se NAN significa "Não é um número", como a função `is_numeric` poderia retornar positivo para NAN?

Por que o resultado de `is_numeric(NAN)` é true?

## Atualização

Para aumentar mais ainda a discussão, outros dois testes revelaram resultados contraditórios:

```
is_float(NAN) // true
filter_var(NAN, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)// false
```

Comment: Sim, eu ainda uso PHP, mas ele paga meu salário :p

Comment: *PHP sendo PHP.*

Comment: Pergunta: "*Is not-a-number a number?*" Resposta: "**YES!**"

Comment: A doc confirmar http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php é float :p ... dificil saber o porque apenas

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento saber que é float é uma coisa, agora saber porque duas funções avaliam com resultados diferentes (sendo que elas checam a mesma coisa) é difícil de aceitar :\

Comment: Oi, eu sou o PHP. `NAN !== NAN`

Comment: Acredito `NaN` seja "numero" do tipo `float`, mas ele é "reservado" para ser "desconsiderado". Pelo que estou lendo NaN possui uma situação que é comum na maioria das linguagens, vou tentar entender e responder.

Comment: Nan acredito nisso :p

Comment: @OnoSendai javascript sendo javascript (`typeof NaN`) ... não to defendendo o PHP, é só pra explicar XD

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento E você por acaso acha que eu ia perder a oportunidade de zoar o PHP? ;)

Comment: @OnoSendai PHP sempre te dará novas oportunidades :)

Comment: Relacionado em inglês: [Why does is_numeric(NAN) return TRUE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554990/why-does-is-numericnan-return-true/40555183#40555183)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `NAN` (`NAN` ou `-NAN`) é um valor diferente de zero com um ponto flutuante, ou seja ele `0.0`, o que é diferente de `0`

Isto é devido ao nível é mais uma questão de "baixo nível" (ou "nível mais baixo"), é algo em como o [processador trabalha (leia sobre FPU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit), ou seja `NaN` usa `0.0` pois é um ponto "não usado", veja a descrição do [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

> In computing, NaN, standing for **not a number**, is a **numeric data type value** representing an undefined or unrepresentable value, especially in floating-point calculations.

Seria algo como:

NaN é um valor do tipo numérico que representa um valor indefinido ou que não pode ser representado, especialmente em cálculos com ponto flutuantes.

E outro trecho do [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante):

> A maioria dos sistemas que operam com ponto flutuante utilizam representações definidas na norma [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).
>
> O padrão IEEE para aritmética de ponto flutuante (IEEE 754) é o padrão mais amplamente utilizado para o cálculo de ponto flutuante, e é seguido por muitos CPU e melhorias FPU. A norma define formatos para representar números de ponto flutuante (incluindo zero) e os valores não normalizados, bem como os valores especiais infinito e NaN, com um conjunto de operações de ponto flutuante que trabalham com esses valores. Também especifica quatro modos de arredondamento e cinco exceções (inclusive quando essas exceções ocorrem é o que acontece nesses momentos).

Ou seja **isto não é um problema do PHP** e sim como o processador/compilador vai trabalhar.

**Uma nota**, em PHP `float`, `double` e "números reais" tem o mesmo tipo de dados, como explicado na documentação http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php:

```
<?php
$a = 1.234; 
$b = 1.2e3; 
$c = 7E-10;
```

Somente no "nível mais baixo" eles são armazenados como `double` geralmente:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.

Answer (score 11):

## Resumo

Resumidamente, a função `is_number()` verifica o tipo somente. Como NAN é uma constante com tipo definido como float, é retornado como true. Já a função `is_float()` retorna `true` por verificar o tipo do "objeto". Teoricamente quase o mesmo que `is_number()`.

No PHP, a constante NAN é definida como *float*, segundo a documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php. Note que INF (infinite) também é tratada como *float*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na função `filter_var()` é feito uma segunda checagem após identificar o tipo, onde provavelmente o NaN não passa, retornando booleano falso. Veja abaixo um detalhamento sobre esse resumo:

## NaN não é igual a NaN

Antes de demonstrar a fonte das funções em questão, é importante entender que é errôneo comparar NAN com NAN pois este representa um estado indefinido.

```
var_dump(NAN == NAN); // retorna false
```

Nunca será igual pois um marcador de estado indefinido nunca é igual a indefinido.

Isso acontece porque NAN não é um valor, é um marcador de posição (placeholder) para um estado indefinido. Na matemática, indefinido não pode ser igual a indefinido (indefinido != indefinido).

Para checar se é um `NAN`, use a função [is_nan()](http://php.net/is_nan).

Esclarecido esse ponto, agora vamos direto na fonte para entender o que realmente acontece. Abaixo, segue os trechos de código relevantes retirados do repositório oficial: https://github.com/php/php-src

## PHP_FUNCTION(is_numeric)

Esse é o source da função is_numeric(): https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/type.c

O trecho que interessa:

```
/* {{{ proto bool is_numeric(mixed value)
   Returns true if value is a number or a numeric string */
PHP_FUNCTION(is_numeric)
{
    zval *arg;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_ZVAL(arg)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    switch (Z_TYPE_P(arg)) {
        case IS_LONG:
        case IS_DOUBLE:
            RETURN_TRUE;
            break;

        case IS_STRING:
            if (is_numeric_string(Z_STRVAL_P(arg), Z_STRLEN_P(arg), NULL, NULL, 0)) {
                RETURN_TRUE;
            } else {
                RETURN_FALSE;
            }
            break;

        default:
            RETURN_FALSE;
            break;
    }
}
```

Não preciso comentar um código tão simples e óbvio. Está óbvio o que acontece e porque retorna true.

Agora note a diferença no tratamento com a função `filter_var()`, abaixo:

## void php_filter_float()

Essa é a função do interpretador do PHP que processa o filtro, da função `filter_var()`: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c

Estou sem ambiente adequado para testar esse simples script, mas olhando superficialmente parece que o valor cai nesse `switch()`:

```
    switch (is_numeric_string(num, p - num, &lval, &dval, 0)) {
        case IS_LONG:
            zval_ptr_dtor(value);
            ZVAL_DOUBLE(value, (double)lval);
            break;
        case IS_DOUBLE:
            if ((!dval && p - num > 1 && strpbrk(num, "123456789")) || !zend_finite(dval)) {
                goto error;
            }
            zval_ptr_dtor(value);
            ZVAL_DOUBLE(value, dval);
            break;
        default:
error:
            efree(num);
            RETURN_VALIDATION_FAILED
    }
```

O NaN pode estar caindo nesse trecho. Mesmo que passe como DOUBLE, pode estar entrando como true nessa condicional, o que leva ao `goto error`

```
            if ((!dval && p - num > 1 && strpbrk(num, "123456789")) || !zend_finite(dval)) {
                goto error;
            }
```

## PHP_FUNCTION(is_float)

Agora vamos ver como o `is_float()` lida com o argumento recebido:

```
static inline void php_is_type(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS, int type)
{
    zval *arg;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_ZVAL_DEREF(arg)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END_EX(RETURN_FALSE);

    if (Z_TYPE_P(arg) == type) {
        if (type == IS_RESOURCE) {
            const char *type_name = zend_rsrc_list_get_rsrc_type(Z_RES_P(arg));
            if (!type_name) {
                RETURN_FALSE;
            }
        }
        RETURN_TRUE;
    } else {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
}

/* {{{ proto bool is_float(mixed var)
   Returns true if variable is float point
   Warning: This function is special-cased by zend_compile.c and so is usually bypassed */
PHP_FUNCTION(is_float)
{
    php_is_type(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU, IS_DOUBLE);
}
```

`Z_TYPE_P()`: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h

```
static zend_always_inline zend_uchar zval_get_type(const zval* pz) {
    return pz->u1.v.type;
}

/* we should never set just Z_TYPE, we should set Z_TYPE_INFO */
#define Z_TYPE(zval)                zval_get_type(&(zval))
#define Z_TYPE_P(zval_p)            Z_TYPE(*(zval_p))
```

## No PHP, double, float e decimal é tudo igual

Alguns podem questionar dizendo que é errado afirmar que float e double são diferentes pois é sabido que no PHP os tipos *double* e *float* são tratados de forma igual, porém, há uma peculiaridade. Em termos computacionais, *double* é diferente de *float* tal como do tipo *decimal*.
Ambos são armazenados de forma diferente na memória. Outras linguagens fortemente tipadas tratam esses 3 tipos como sendo diferentes.

Para maior esclarecimento:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double

<sub>*Há diversas outras fontes. Não baseie-se somente em links de stackoverflow. 
Esse assunto desvia do foco da questão, portanto, não abordarei com mais detalhes.</sub>

## Consideração final

Observando os códigos das 3 funções, `is_numeric()`, `is_float()` e `filter_var()`, podemos ver que não há uma checagem "profunda". É meramente uma questão de tratamento do argumento recebido. Enquanto que as duas primeiras não checam o real valor, confiando na definição da tipagem, `filter_var()` possui uma segunda condicional que talvez, "acidentalmente", retorna false para o NAN.

Também podemos observar que os resultados de ambas as funções não tem relação direta com a arquitetura da CPU como poderíamos pressupor.

Um fato relevante é, uma vez ciente o que NaN é sempre diferente de NaN, não faz sentido fazer quaisquer operações com esse "objeto".

Para maior consistência nos códigos, caso esteja lidando com expressões matemáticas, aplique a função `is_nan()` antes de qualquer coisa.

Isso é válido em praticamente qualquer linguagem.

## Curiosidades

```
echo gettype(NAN); // retorna "double"
var_dump(NAN); //retorna "float(NAN)".
var_dump(empty(NAN)); //retorna "bool(false)".
```

Trecho do código fonte de `gettype()`:

```
case IS_DOUBLE:
    RETVAL_STRING("double");
    break;
```

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/type.c (linha 48)

## Flames e haters

Referente a comentários improdutivos feitos por [haters](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hater_(internet)) do PHP e [flamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaming_(Internet)).

Conforme mencionado nos parágrafos acima, matematicamente um valor *indefinido* não pode ser igual a outro *indefinido*. Esse é o caso do NaN.
Alguns comentários nesta página dão a entender que se trata de arbitrariedade do PHP, pejorativamente. Para os mais experientes é inofensivo, porém, dissemina desinformação aos que não entendem do assunto. Ou seja, dissemina ignorância.

Praticamente todas as linguagens de programação seguem a mesma regra para o NaN e o definem como float também.

Comment: Errado. `double` e `float` no PHP é a mesma coisa.  [Exemplo](http://ideone.com/0csWtq)

Comment: `var_dump((double)1.5 === (float) 1.5); // true`

Comment: Eu esperava que alguém fosse dizer isso, mas aí que te pego rsr.. Na verdade não Wallace, pois float é diferente de double. Ambos são armazenados de forma diferente na memória. Essa é a diferença. Mas como não é esse o foco da questão, por isso evitei desviar o assunto para esse lado.

Comment: Na verdade não Wallace, pois float é diferente de double. Ambos são armazenados de forma diferente. Essa é a diferença.

Comment: E o `is_numeric` fica onde?

Comment: [Difference between float and double in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3280927/3096922)

Comment: is_numeric é a mesma situação do is_float(), não compara o tipo.

Comment: Inclusive [a documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php) fala que `doubleval` é alias para `floatval`. Tem diferença?

Comment: Aí que está Wallace, no php, decimal, double e float é tudo tratado como float. as funções antigas foram escritas dessa forma. É simples assim. Já a função filter_var() trouxe mais consistência em verificar o "real" tipo.

Comment: Pegue uma linguagem fortemente tipada, exemplo, o Objective-C. Nessa linguagem, float, decimal e double são tipos diferentes. O PHP, nos primórdios de seu desenvolvimento, provavelmente quis "resumir" e tratar tudo como float. Mas enfim, antes de sair negativando, dê uma pesquisada pelo menos.. rsrrsr aliás são assuntos básicos de computação...

Comment: A única diferença é a seguinte: *Variáveis float exigem 4 bytes de memória para serem armazenadas, já double necessitam de 8 bytes.* A utilidade é a mesma.

Comment: Mauro, Exato.. é assim que o PHP interpretou, a utilidade, a funcionalidade.. mas em termos de armazenamento são diferentes.

Comment: Com a edição e a explicação das funções, a resposta ficou muito boa. +1