# ParseInt() está retornando NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
arrayCods = lista.split(",");
var i_rem = document.getElementById('listaUsuarios').value;

//Até aqui tudo bem, a i_rem contém um valor numérico extraído do html.
i_rem = arrayCods[i_rem];
console.log("Irem1:  " +i_rem);  //IMPRIME CORRETAMENTE O NÚMERO CONTIDO NA STRING
console.log(typeof(i_rem));  // TUDO CERTO AQUI. I_REM É UMA STRING

var numero = parseInt(i_rem);
console.log(numero); // AQUI RETORNA NAN
console.log(typeof(numero));  // MAS ISSO RETORNA CORRETAMENTE DIZENDO QUE O  TIPO DA VARIÁVEL NUMER É NUMBER. SE É NUMBER, COMO AO IMPRIMI-LO TENHO UM NAN??
```

Como expliquei nos comentários, ao imprimir a variável, o console imprime NaN, mas ao imprimir typeof da variável, retorna Number. Então porque não consigo obter esse número, porque retorna NaN?

Comment: Deve ser a mesma coisa que isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165021/por-que-a-constante-nan-%C3%A9-avaliada-como-verdadeiro-ao-test%C3%A1-la-com-is-numeric

Comment: Você tem que testar como está o número antes do parseInt com console.log

Comment: Eu testei, e retorna o número: console.log("Irem1:  " +i_rem);   Imprime na console: Irem1:  "3"

Comment: Não é php, é javascript

Comment: `typeof NaN === typeof 0 //return true`, ou seja, `NaN` é do tipo `Number` porém não é um número válido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `parseInt` não te garante que o valor é de fato um número, ele apenas converte o tipo.

Veja o que você comentou:

> Eu testei, e retorna o número: console.log("Irem1: " +i_rem); Imprime
>   na console: Irem1: "3"

Nota-se que o valor recebido é um número entre aspas duplas: `"3"`.

Com isso, as aspas invalidam o número, tornando-o `NaN`.

Até mesmo uma letra dentro de um `parseInt` retorna tipo `number`, veja:

```js
var numero = parseInt("a");
console.log(numero);
console.log(typeof(numero));
```

Pelo visto a array gerada pelo código `arrayCods = lista.split(",");` está retornando valores com aspas duplas, e por isso gera o NaN.

A solução é remover as aspas com `.replace`:

```
// remove todas as aspas duplas
i_rem = arrayCods[i_rem].replace(/"/g,'');
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
lista = '"1", "2", "3"';
arrayCods = lista.split(",");
//var arrayCods = ["1","2","3"];
var i_rem = document.getElementById('listaUsuarios').value;

//Até aqui tudo bem, a i_rem contém um valor numérico extraído do html.
i_rem = arrayCods[i_rem].replace(/"/g,'');
console.log("Irem1:  " +i_rem);  //IMPRIME CORRETAMENTE O NÚMERO CONTIDO NA STRING
console.log(typeof(i_rem));  // TUDO CERTO AQUI. I_REM É UMA STRING

var numero = parseInt(i_rem);
console.log(numero); // AQUI RETORNA NAN
console.log(typeof(numero));  // MAS ISSO RETORNA CORRETAMENTE DIZENDO QUE O  TIPO DA VARIÁVEL NUMER É NUMBER. SE É NUMBER, COMO AO IMPRIMI-LO TENHO UM NAN??
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listaUsuarios" value="2">
```

**Alternativa ao replace:**

Você também pode usar `.match` para pegar apenas o número da string:

```
i_rem = arrayCods[i_rem].match(/\d+/)[0];
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
lista = '"1", "2", "3"';
arrayCods = lista.split(",");
//var arrayCods = ["1","2","3"];
var i_rem = document.getElementById('listaUsuarios').value;

//Até aqui tudo bem, a i_rem contém um valor numérico extraído do html.
i_rem = arrayCods[i_rem].match(/\d+/)[0];
console.log("Irem1:  " +i_rem);  //IMPRIME CORRETAMENTE O NÚMERO CONTIDO NA STRING
console.log(typeof(i_rem));  // TUDO CERTO AQUI. I_REM É UMA STRING

var numero = parseInt(i_rem);
console.log(numero); // AQUI RETORNA NAN
console.log(typeof(numero));  // MAS ISSO RETORNA CORRETAMENTE DIZENDO QUE O  TIPO DA VARIÁVEL NUMER É NUMBER. SE É NUMBER, COMO AO IMPRIMI-LO TENHO UM NAN??
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listaUsuarios" value="2">
```