# Soma de 2 valores com botão em AngularJS

Tags: html5, angularjs

Queria saber oque está dando de errado porque quando faço a função do `ng-click` no HTML o `{{resultado}}` aparece como **NaN**.

**HTML**

```
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ngclick="juntarTotal()">
          Juntar os dois campos
        </button>

        <h3>{{resultado}}</h3>
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('doisnumerosController', function($scope){
    $scope.juntarTotal = () => {
      $scope.resultado = $scope.valor1 + $scope.valor2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Primeiro mostre os valores de `$scope.valor1` e valor2, veja se tem valor e se são numéricos. Caso necessário converta para números para fazer a soma, exemplo `Number($scope.valor1)`

Comment: [**O que significa NaN no javascript?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92169)

Comment: Meu input ta como "number". 
`$scope.juntarTotal = () => { 
$scope.resultado = Number($scope.valor1) + Number($scope.valor2;) }` 
@RicardoPontual, tipo assim?

Comment: Isso, para garantir que os valores sejam somados como números

Comment: Mas não está dando, o valor do {{resultado}} no html continua dando NaN, pode me ajudar com algum exemplo @RicardoPontual?

Comment: NaN significa que não é um número (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Comment: Significa que um dos seus valores não é número, precisa ver qual é.. no exemplo que você colocou, o ponto-e-vírgula está dentro do parênteses da function o que dá erro: `Number($scope.valor2;)` se você usou assim no código dá erro, o correto é `Number($scope.valor2);`